# Getting all the lines passing through 3 or more points from a given set of N points (on a plane)

Tags: python, math, geometry, mathematical-optimization

This is my first question here. Pls lemme know if I'm unclear...

I need to find all **the unique regressed lines** which are touching **or near (within a given tolerance)** 3 or more points for a given set of N points on a plane

A simple brute force approach is to find all 3 or more points combinations from these N points and check if the corresponding regressed lines within the input tolerance

By tolerance, I mean, average absolute distance between each point and the corresponding point on the regressed line

Comment: Can you please explain more about what you are asking and present a piece of code? Thank you so much

Comment: Thanks El.Ham. I use python but haven't started coding on this yet. Need to formulate my approach first.

Comment: I think you need to reformulate what you actually want. Mathematically there are likely to be infinitely many such lines. For example if a line passes within say half the tolerance iof three points, then a small enough change to the line parameters will mean the changed line passes within the tolerance of the three points. Practically you won;t get infinitely many lines but could get a gigantic number of them

Comment: @dmuir, I don't think it is necessarily that bad. Theoretically you can merge similar lines into one line selected by some rule. Still there is a question how to find all such lines efficiently. I can't come up with anything better than checking all lines specified by all pairs of points and then doing the merging. Do you have any better ideas?

Comment: Glad that you mentioned it SerGr. My response would have been the same. Pls note: my question is to find all the unique (3 or more) points which are touching or near the same regressed line (within a tolerance).